# Placing View Underneath Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-4.4-kitkat

I have a custom camera activity in my Android app.  For android devices using KitKat, I needed to account for the visible navigation bar at the bottom of the screen.  To do this, I use the following line to ensure my views are below the navigation bar:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN );
```

However, when I do this, one of my views becomes hidden behind the action bar.  I'm trying to account for the height of the action bar by adding a top margin to this view, but it doesn't appear to be correct.

What am I doing wrong?

This is what I would like the view to look like (works on pre-KitKat devices):

[image]

And this is what it currently looks like on Kit Kat devices (you can see that the top of my view is cut off):
[image]

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/gallery_scroll_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" >

        <com.example.helperClass.PictureHorizontalLayout
            android:id="@+id/mygallery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" >
        </com.example.helperClass.PictureHorizontalLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camerapreview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/black" />   

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/button_holder_customized_cam"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#838B8B"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="0.9"
        >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/gallery_customized_camera"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/add"
            android:maxWidth="75dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_picture" >

            <!-- android:background="@drawable/custom_button_blue" -->

        </ImageButton>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/shutter_customized_camera"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@drawable/custom_button_blue"
            android:contentDescription="@string/add"
            android:maxWidth="75dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_camera" >
        </ImageButton>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/video_customized_camera"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:background="@null"
            android:contentDescription="@string/add"
            android:maxWidth="75dp"
            android:scaleType="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_video" >

            <!-- android:background="@drawable/custom_button_blue" -->

        </ImageButton>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/camera_timer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/button_holder_customized_cam"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:text="@string/no_time"
        android:textColor="@color/red"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:visibility="invisible" >
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here is how I set margins for the HorizontalScrollView:

```
  myHorizontalLayout = (PictureHorizontalLayout) findViewById(R.id.mygallery);
  // apply margin to horizontal scroll view to take into account height of status bar
    TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
    int actionBarHeight  = 0;
    if (getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true))
    {
        actionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data,getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        Log.d(TAG, "actionbarHeight before: " + actionBarHeight);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) myHorizontalLayout.getLayoutParams();
        Log.d(TAG, "actionbarHeight after: " + actionBarHeight);
        params.setMargins(0, actionBarHeight, 0, 0);
        Log.d(TAG, "ADJUST MARGINS OF HORIZONTAL LAYOUT");
        myHorizontalLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
```

NOTE: I also tried adding `android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` to the HorizontalScrollView in my layout file, but this didn't work either (the vertical offset was still incorrect)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `RelativeLayout` to use the `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` attribute.

From the `View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE` docs:

> When using other layout flags, we would like a stable view of the
>   content insets given to fitSystemWindows(Rect).

Also, the attribute `android:orientation` isn't inherited by `RealtiveLayout` and `android:scaleType` isn't inherited by `HorizontalScrollView`.

Comment: thanks for your help.  when I add this to my layout, the horizontal scroll appears far below my action bar, not directly below it.

Comment: @scientiffic Stop calling `myHorizontalLayout.setLayoutParams(params);`.

Comment: Yes, I had already moved that line before I tested it, and it still appears incorrectly: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1000620/Untitled-2.png

Comment: @scientiffic Then you must be using `?attr/actionBarSize` somewhere because that space is the same as the `ActionBar` height.

Comment: you were right, I was calling it accidentally.  thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The best way to do what you want, is to use ActionBar in [Overlay Mode](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/overlaying.html).
Then, you can use the following margin in your view to make sure it does not hide behind the action bar.

```
<!-- Support library compatibility -->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: for some reading, adding this line changes the aspect ratio of the image in my camera preview, so it doesn't work for me unfortunately.

Comment: You could add this padding only to the view that was hidden, not the whole RelativeLayout. Anyway, you found a solution, so problem solved. Keep up!